# SQL multiple joins while dealing with null values

Tags: sql, join, null

I have a question regarding SQL syntax and how my query should be done.

I have atm conquered my problem using two queries and some PHP.
However, let me present my DB and problem.

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbISx.png)

With the unique ID of the print table i want to be able to get:

1. dex number from prints
2. image (URL) from prints
3. rarity from rarities
4. type from types x3 when not null else i still want to execute
5. name from pokemon x5 when not null else i still want to execute

The query is quite simple when it comes to collecting all the values

```
SELECT pr.dex, 
       pr.image, 
       p.name, 
       r.rarity, 
       t.type, 
       t2.type, 
       t3.type,
       p1.name,
       p2.name,
       p3.name,
       p4.name
FROM prints pr
       JOIN pokemons p ON p.dex=pr.dex
       JOIN rarities r ON r.id=pr.rarity
       JOIN types t ON t.id=p.type
       JOIN types t2 ON t2.id=pr.weakness
       JOIN types t3 ON t3.id=pr.resistance
       JOIN pokemons p1 ON p1.dex=p.evolveto
       JOIN pokemons p2 ON p2.dex=p.evolveto2
       JOIN pokemons p3 ON p3.dex=p.evolveto3
       JOIN pokemons p4 ON p4.dex=p.evolvefrom
WHERE pr.id=2;
```

But for some `pr.id(s)` the values for `pr.weakness`, `pr.resistance`, `p.evolveto`, `p.evolveto2`, `p.evolveto3` or `p.evolvefrom` can and should be null.

When any of them are null the query comes back empty.

So basically what I want is to exclude values which are null.

I've tried to wrap in some selects with `COALESCE()` and played around a bit with `CASE` but without success. It would be awesome if it can be done with only one query regardless of what value `pr.id` has.

Comment: What did you try? This sounds like you should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. COALESCE could also be an option, but then you have to coalesce both values by the same value. Could you please provide sample input and expected outcome? And maybe put the focus on two or three tables only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INNER JOINs feature ON clauses that do equijoin on a possibly NULL field.
Yet you want to get a row back anyway,
showing that the given field was empty.

The tool you're looking for is LEFT OUTER JOIN,
which will do exactly that.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

For example

```
SELECT cat.name, cat.price, inv.qty, inv.date
FROM catalog cat
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory inv  ON cat.id = inv.cat_id
```

will reveal catalog items even if they've not been inventoried.

An expression like `COALESCE(inv.qty, 0)`
can be handy for suppressing NULLs
in the result rows, if desired.

Comment: You are the best. I wonder why i havent encounter ´LEFT OUTER JOIN´ when roaming the internet. However thanks a thousand it works! (but that you already knew)
And thanks for a fast answer!

Comment: That's because there is no difference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN, so therefore most people just write LEFT JOIN (I already mentioned you will likely need to do this in my comment above).